# How do I split sentence into blocks of fixed length without breaking words efficiently?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

INPUT: "This process was continued for several years for the deaf child does not here in a month or even in two or three years the numberless items and expressions using the simplest daily intercourse little hearing child learns from these constant rotation and imitation the conversation he hears in his home simulates is mine and suggest topics and called forth the spontaneous expression of his own thoughts."

CHUNK_SIZE: 200, ( lets say its 200 characters long ).

OUTPUT:

> ["This process was continued for several years for the deaf child does not here in a month or even in two or three years the numberless items and expressions using the simplest daily intercourse little",
>
> "hearing child learns from these constant rotation and imitation the conversation he hears in his home simulates is mine and suggest topics and called forth the spontaneous expression of his own",
>
> "thoughts."]

I know one way of doing it is by calculating length and checking if I'm breaking any word and all that, but someone told me thats highly inefficient and unadvisable.. so here I am asking for help.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use a regular expression to match 200 characters, greedily, and have it backtrack until the last character matched is followed by a space character or the end of the string:

```js
const str = "This process was continued for several years for the deaf child does not here in a month or even in two or three years the numberless items and expressions using the simplest daily intercourse little hearing child learns from these constant rotation and imitation the conversation he hears in his home simulates is mine and suggest topics and called forth the spontaneous expression of his own thoughts.";
const chunks = str.match(/.{1,200}(?= |$)/g);
console.log(chunks);
```

If you want to exclude leading/trailing spaces as well, add `\S` to the beginning and end of the match:

```js
const str = "This process was continued for several years for the deaf child does not here in a month or even in two or three years the numberless items and expressions using the simplest daily intercourse little hearing child learns from these constant rotation and imitation the conversation he hears in his home simulates is mine and suggest topics and called forth the spontaneous expression of his own thoughts.";
const chunks = str.match(/\S.{1,198}\S(?= |$)/g);
console.log(chunks);
```

To use a variable:

```js
const chunkSize = 200;
const str = "This process was continued for several years for the deaf child does not here in a month or even in two or three years the numberless items and expressions using the simplest daily intercourse little hearing child learns from these constant rotation and imitation the conversation he hears in his home simulates is mine and suggest topics and called forth the spontaneous expression of his own thoughts.";
const chunks = str.match(new RegExp(String.raw`\S.{1,${chunkSize - 2}}\S(?= |$)`, 'g'));
console.log(chunks);
```

If you also need to account for the possibility that there's only one character, don't require two or more characters to be matched in the pattern:

```js
const chunkSize = 200;
const str = "This process was continued for several years for the deaf child does not here in a month or even in two or three years the numberless items and expressions using the simplest daily intercourse little hearing child learns from these constant rotation and imitation the conversation he hears in his home simulates is mine and suggest topics and called forth the spontaneous expression of his own thoughts.";
const chunks = str.match(new RegExp(String.raw`\S(?:.{0,${chunkSize - 2}}\S)?(?= |$)`, 'g'));
console.log(chunks);
```

Comment: This is such a great answer :) I almost forget to use lookahead and this is a perfect example on when they can be useful.

Comment: Hey @CertainPerformance, It doesn't match if the original string was just "a".

Comment: @xaovnumwsercy Then don't require that the pattern match at least 2 characters